# How to update custom price for product in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.8

I want to set different prices for different customers. Can anyone tell me which are the correct events(Observers) to update price for the customer after he/she logged in?

1) Want to show custom price for him/her

2) If customer added product to cart and then he/she logged in then want update quote items prices.

Answer (score 0):

You can set product custom price by below code

> app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
    <observer name="customprice" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\CustomPrice" />
</event>
```

> app/code/Namespace/Module/Observer/CustomPrice.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $price = "YourCustomPrice" //You can set your cucstom price here
            $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
            $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this event will satisfy my 2nd condition?

Comment: You can use this code for update product price when customer add to cart product.

Comment: Any other suggestions?